# How can I automatically pair my phone with my windows 8 laptop?

Tags: android, matlab, windows-8, command-line, bluetooth

I am using Windows 8 laptop (system controller), MATLAB R2013a (programming software and I will like to automatically pair my android phone with my laptop. I am developing a prototype of an embedded system.

Currently, I am using BTPAIR function from the Bluetooth Command Line Tools (system('btpair') in Matlab). This works but I have to accept the pairing request on my laptop and my phone. I dont want to have to manually accept the pairing request on my laptop.

Is there a way I programmatically get my laptop to accept the pairing request after I accepted the request on my phone?

Comment: Why do you need to automate the pairing? Once paired, there is no need to pair again.

Comment: Yes you have a good point. In the future, I will like to pair the embedded controller to another device. I wouldnt have the luxury of clicking my laptop.